# Pivot text columns Row to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have columns like this

```
    FIELDPID    FIELDNAME   VALUE
     12       COMPANY_NAME  Bristol bb
     12       CP_ID         47957
     12       CPID_TYPE         ORG
     67       COMPANY_NAME  PRODUCTS LTD
     67       CP_ID         47957
     67       CPID_TYPE     ORG
     69       COMPANY_NAME  PRODUCTS LTD
     69       CP_ID         47957
     69       CPID_TYPE     IND
```

i want the result as

FIELDPID,COMPANY_NAME,CP_ID,CPID_TYPE

```
FIELDPID    COMPANY_NAME    CP_ID   CPID_TYPE
    12      Bristol bb      47957   ORG
    67      PRODUCTS LTD    47975   ORG
```

validations the cpid_type has to be only "org"
Thanks  for the help
Arun

Comment: check out this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx

Comment: See my edit in my answer for the issue you added, you can also comment in the answer instead of editing the answer

Answer (score 2):

Use the `PIVOT` table operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename AS t
PIVOT
(
   MAX(Value)
   FOR FieldName IN([COMPANY_NAME],
                    [CP_ID],
                    [CPID_TYPE])
) AS p;
```

---

**Update:**

If you want to add a condition for the `CPID_TYPE` you can do this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM tablename AS t
    PIVOT
    (
       MAX(Value)
       FOR FieldName IN([COMPANY_NAME],
                        [CP_ID],
                        [CPID_TYPE])
    ) AS p
) 
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE CPID_TYPE = 'ORG';
```

Comment: +1 for posting the correct answer first and within just 3 minutes of question being asked

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a little mistake in your data. In case of

```
 13       CPID_TYPE         ORG
```

can be changed to

```
 12       CPID_TYPE         ORG
```

the result query will be as `Mahmoud Gamal` mentioned:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename AS t
PIVOT
(
   MAX(Value)
   FOR FIELDPID IN([COMPANY_NAME],
                    [CP_ID],
                    [CPID_TYPE])
) AS p
```

And the results will be correct. Additional information according to `PIVOT` can be found here: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: so don't post the same answer as `Mahmoud Gamal`

Comment: The point is that there's an error in the default data posted by `Arun Kumar`

Comment: write that in a comment